# Can "Toggle Quad view" remember the viewpoint?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

When I click twice on *Toggle Quad View*, it let me with an ortho-view instead of the previous 3D view, forcing me to find the viewpoint I had previously again. Is there an option to remember the viewpoint? Hitting Numpad 0 to toggle between current viewpoint and camera view works.

Answer (score 6):

When toggling off by pressing button, it will switch to the Front ortho view by default. But you can hover the mouse cursor over one of the four views, then use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle off while switching to that particular view.

Comment: Nice workaround. However, the question was about remember the view. In that case, it just uses the mouse cursor position. As it's not an easy shortcut, I think it would be better to make the button work like the Numpad 0 view toggle. I guess another thing that will get lost about usability...

Comment: @matali you can right click on the the button, then choose **Change Shortcut** to change it to a relatively easier one that is not used yet, for example: **Q**.  :)

Comment: Actually, i was in the camera view as I tried it the first time so I didn't notice it, but in my case it really overwrites my viewpoint. If I go in quadview then back from the camera view, then hit Numpad 0, it gives me an orthoview, instead of my original viewpoint.

Comment: Although I cannot fully get your point, but I agree with you on some possible improvement here.

Comment: The toogle quadview operator should offer an option to remember views, or even share the top right view with the single 3d view. That would be a nice feature!

Comment: Things are moving thanks to Sebastien :) P21 https://developer.blender.org/file/data/id3bebwpkekwtbpbhlk2/PHID-FILE-4byjulgb2k37tyhqp4tu/Fix_for_T39028 and P22 https://developer.blender.org/file/data/m3qopromf54vmswkthjh/PHID-FILE-4aysthuav277wgjuwnjo/Fix_for_T39039 look both really promising. Thanks CoDEmanX for reporting too :)

Answer (score 2):

The Quad View is comprised of the: Top, Front, Right, Camera views. There is no way of changing this. However there is a workaround/hack for this. Since you want to always return to the same perspective viewport you can use your camera as the perspective view.

1. Go into your camera view

   [image]
2. Zoom in to where you can no longer see the border of the camera. This will look you standard viewport.

   [image]
3. In the properties panel under **View** enable **Lock Camera to View**

   [image]

The camera is now locked the the viewport. So when you go between quad and perspective view it will remember where you left off.

[image]

Comment: One can actually change all 4 views in quadview mode if one disables *Lock* in the *Display* panel (N toolshelf)

Comment: @CoDEmanX that's is not working for me like OP wants

Comment: It won't remember views, but it's at least possible to change all four. But I can't find a way to access all four in script? Looks like incomplete API...

Comment: Nice workaround Vader :) I tried using it in a real case, if the Camera is animated, changing frame or saving/loading breaks it. I'll try to propose a fix here, but it will most certainly be seen as an expected behaviour. @CoDEmanX I hope you find an API hack, maybe with a custom scene parameter to store the point of view and an operator that calls the quad view and immediately change the 3Dview to that point. I couldn't find how to get the right context after an hour reading the doc and trying different operators and paths...

Comment: Access to view3d view parameters is not a problem for region_3d, but for region_quadview, it really looks like missing/broken API - reported: https://developer.blender.org/T39028

Comment: @matali you can always have multiple cameras

Comment: @Vader but the Quadview and Render both use the active camera. I tried but can't get how to have a "Quadview camera" and a "render camera"

Comment: @matali that is an unfortunate limitation.

Comment: Hi people!
I've just encountered this problem too. After pressing Ctrl+Alt+Q I switch to Quad View. I need to maximize Top Ortho. Hovered cursor over Top, pressed hotkey and... it switched me back into Camera View! "Lock" option checked. If it's unchecked Top is maximized but after pressing hotkey again my Camera View replaced with Top :(

Comment: to change the default quad view read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view

Answer (score 1):

The solution to let Blender remember the view on hover is that the checkbox *Lock* under the *Quad View*-Button has to be disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally Blender starts in the "User Persp" view but as soon as you go to the quad view, Blender switches to the "User Ortho" view. You can toggle between both modes with <kbd>NumPad 5</kbd> key.

More info: [Perspective and Orthographic Projection](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View)