# How to change the default views of quad view?

Tags: 3d-view

How do I change the TOP ortho view to BACK ortho view for my BACK image?

check out the pic I uploaded to see what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make the view in that section look from the back? Or do you want to adjust your model so that the back view looks like the current top view?

Answer (score 34):

Quad view can be unlocked and customized.

**For blender 2.8**

Select quad view.

(<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> or select View > Area > Toggle Quad View

Open the properties panel on the right and unselect  "lock".
[image]

**To customize the view** move the mouse over to the quad you want to alter and make it whatever [view](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#Aligning_the_View) you want.

In this case press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> for back view. (and <kbd>Numpad 5<</kbd> to toggle ortho or perspective).

[image]

**Note: Any changes on quad view are lost once you go back to single view**: The next time you switch to quad view it will revert to the default configuration.

---

For older versions (2.7x) of blender

While on **Quad view** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the **Properties panel** on the right side. In the **Display tab** uncheck the **Lock** box.

[image]

When you are satisfied you can lock the view again to prevent accidental changes.

To reverse the view on quad view. Hover over the view you want to change and press **<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd>**  to reverse the view. No need to press unlock

[image]

Comment: +1 Wow, never new that! ([even the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#Quad_View) doesn't know that ;)