# i was doing Blender guru`s tutorial when out of the flash this happen, how do i solve it?:

Tags: modeling

[image]

[2]: i already tried the merge thing with the corners didn`t work

Comment: You are in quad view https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101938/how-do-i-get-4-view-points-in-blender

Answer (score 0):

This is *Quad View*; it's toggled on and off using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>