# Is there a way to get Blender to remember my view settings?

Tags: 3d-view

I prefer my Blender set up with four view windows, like in this example:

[image: blender view]

However, every time I begin a new model, I'm presented with the default single view, and I have to re-establish the other three windows and perspectives, as well as reset other preferences, like the grid size.

How can I get Blender to remember my settings across models?

Comment: Configure the screen the way you want it.  Press Ctrl+U to save as startup file and enable Load UI in the system preferences. The saved layout will become the default layout. Also consider using  **Quad View** (Ctrl+Alt+Q) instead of 4 3D viewport windows

Comment: Technically a different question, but the exact same answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this quad view is even better.  Now the view doesn't get messed up every time I accidentally hit the middle mouse button.  I've been trying to figure that one out for months...

Comment: Having many windows open is a waste of screen Real Estate. Also note that quad view can also be customized. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view/18322#18322