# How to change the default views of quad view in blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

I have the same question as [How to change the default views of quad view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/how-to-change-the-default-views-of-quad-view) but for Blender 2.8 where you can not press N to display the View Properties.

I would like to have a 3ds max view and change the viewports accordingly.

Comment: I have made a proposal for this Quad view feature in blender. You can check this out
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/lRWM/?sorting=hot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the *3D View* header menu, under *View > Area > Toggle Quad View*.

Once in quad view, in the sidebar area under the *View* tab a new panel will appear with the *Quad View* options.

[image]

Comment: I prefer to keep it here, but it seems to be weird, click now the link in OP.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it can be closed as duplicate then.

Comment: As I said (and commented on older thread) I prefer to keep it. Easier (faster) for followers to get answer. But you are the boss :)